# How can I mount an Artifactory repository as a Windows drive using non anonymous?

Tags: windows, authentication, webdav, artifactory

I discovered that if the Artifactory repository allows anonymous read, Windows will not ask for credentials but will mount it as read only.

I tried to use `https://username@repo.example.com/reponame` but Windows complains about invalid format.

It seems that jFrog does not cover Windows mounts on their documentaton https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+WebDAV

Any change of solving this?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Davfs2 does not use preemptive authentication. Therefore, in order to authenticate using the user credentials, the client must be authenticated using two requests. The first request is sent without credentials, and receives a 401 challenge in response. Then, a second request is sent, this time with the credentials.
If Artifactory is configured to allow anonymous access it will accept the first request and will not send the challenge. In this case you will get file access with anonymous user permissions which may be less than your own user permissions.
For WebDav clients, which allows manipulating the request headers, you can work around this behavior by sending the Authorization header (forcing preemptive authentication). However I do not think this is possible with the Windows WebClient service.